# htaccess redirection not working on parameters

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We're looking to migrate our site from a really bad hosted ecommerce platform to WordPress.

1/2 of our URL redirects are solid as a rock in htaccess using typical 301 redirects. The current ecommerce site has some strange url parameters:

```
http://thisisthedomain.com/Item_Details?m8:item=1
```

This is essentially the same thing for about 300+ URLs, with only the numerical after the item= changing.

We've tried the following separately:

```
redirect 301 /Item_Details?m8:item=0110 http://finaldomain.com/
redirect 301 /Item_Details%3Fm8%3Aitem%3D0110 http://finaldomain.com/
RewriteRule /Item_Details?m8:item=0110 http://finaldomain.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Item_Details%3Fm8%3Aitem%3D0110$ http://finaldomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

None of them work. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in the pattern of a `RewriteRule` or in a `Redirect`/`RedirectMatch`. You need to use a `RewriteCond` and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m8:item=
RewriteRule ^Item_Details$ http://finaldomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. One follow-up question. Some of the URLs do have redirects that are not for the homepage but another specific page. For example: http://finaldomain.com/Item_Details?m8:item=0112 will need to be redirected to http://finaldomain.com/new-page/.

Comment: @cinemafunk just change `http://finaldomain.com/` to whatever you want it to be redirected to